# How to fetch all historically available hourly weather data?

Tags: time-series, dataset

Where can I obtain all hourly weather data available?

Notes:

- Ideally, this would include the history of all data currently published at:

  - [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130330222141/http://weather.noaa.gov/pub/SL.us008001/DF.an/DC.sflnd/DS.synop/)
  - [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130619050420/http://weather.noaa.gov/pub/SL.us008001/DF.an/DC.sflnd/DS.metar/)
  - [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130619050800/http://weather.noaa.gov/pub/SL.us008001/DF.an/DC.sfmar/DS.ships/)
- I've obtained 10 years of METAR data from wunderground.com like this:

  ```
  curl -H 'Cookie: Prefs=|SHOWMETAR:1|;' -o data.txt 'http://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/KABQ/2005/05/02/DailyHistory.html?req_city=NA&req_state=NA&req_statename=NA&theprefset=SHOWMETAR&theprefvalue=1&format=1'
  ```

but am sure there's a better way.

- I'd love per-minute/etc data too, though I don't think anyone kept
  measurements better than hourly back then.

Answer (score 3):

This may be simplistic, but if you have a consistent directory structure on the NOAA site (they usually are), you can recursive wget the entire thing, then sort through it at your leisure.

```
wget -r http://weather.noaa.gov/pub/SL.us008001/DF.an/
```

This will grab everything recursively from that URL and deeper. It's what I normally use when I want a huge whack of data from some (typically government site) and they do silly things like store it in 1-file-per-hour and I need 12 years worth.

As an aside, I presume you only want historical weather data for the United States? If you're working on this on a slightly longer scale and more global, the Berkeley Earth Surface Temperature Project should be releasing their raw data set in the next few months: see [here](http://berkeleyearth.org/dataset).

Comment: Thanks. Actually I already do that
(https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/bc-get-cycle-files.pl),
but that data only goes back 24 or so hours and isn't archived as far 
as I can tell. I am looking for international data. As an example, 
http://ns1.data.barrycarter.info/HOURLY/ is what I have so far. I took 
a look at the berkeleyearth.org site. The dataset sounds exciting, 
though I wonder if "4 daily and 6 monthly" means they have no hourly 
data?